# "Cannot resolve to object. Type and Subtype X'0203' Authority X'0000" error occurs when a RPGLE program is called via CGI

Tags: cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am calling an RPGLE program via CGI. The RPGLE program calls a few procedures of a service program that is bound to it.

Most of the time, the program works fine but some times it throws below error, saying it cannot resolve the service program object.

MCH3401 - Cannot resolve to object MYSRVPGM. Type and Subtype X'0203'
Authority X'0000'

Note: I did not change anything in the code or library list and the program is always invoked in the same environment

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CGI is always invoked with the same library list...

And that the *SRVPGM wasn't deleted (and subsequently recreated) when the CGI program was invoked...

Then such strange run-time errors might be cause by a parameter mismatch corrupting memory.

Check the parms being used to call any programs or procedures, not just the MYSRVPGM procedures.

Specifically, if you've got local duplicates of prototypes, meaning instead of /COPY'ing the PR into both the caller and callee, you've coded the PR separately in both caller and callee.

Also anyplace where you're using a non-prototyped call.